# Java loop can't iterate down string length

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is some basic code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String string = "Hello!";
System.out.println("First loop.");
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("g");
}
System.out.println("Second loop.");
for (int i = (string.length() - 1); i <= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("g");
}
}
```

For some reason, the program won't go through the second loop at all. This is somewhat strange. Can you explain this, and how to fix it?

Comment: look at you loop condition.

Comment: What is the value of `(string.length() - 1);` ? Is `i <= 0` evaluated to true before starting the first iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second loop should be looping backwards, while the index is still greater than or equal to zero, not less than or equal to zero.  With `<= 0`, `i` is greater than zero on the first evaluation and the loop never runs.

Try:

```
for (int i = (string.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the for condition,the `i` is initial with value greater than 0 (length-1) and there is condition i <= 0 which is true in case length is equal to 1.But the length of string is 6 so change the condition as below :

```
for (int i = (string.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("g");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the condition in the second for loop

```
i <= 0
```

never happens. I don't understand why you would want to check that.